# Jupyter NotebookでWord Cloudを作成したいのですが、画質が粗いです。

Tags: python, 機械学習, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter NotebookでWord Cloudを作成したいのですが、添付画像のように画質が粗いです。
画質をよくする方法を教えて下さい。コードはPythonで書いています。

[image: 出力画像]

コードは以下です。

```
import pandas as pd

from janome.tokenizer import Tokenizer

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

## データ読み込み
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None)
## タイトルを付与
df = df.rename(columns={0:'sentences'})
df.head()

## 関数群の定義
def get_nouns(sentence, noun_list):
    for token in t.tokenize(sentence):
        split_token = token.part_of_speech.split(',')
        ## 一般名詞を抽出
        if split_token[0] == '名詞' and split_token[1] == '一般':
            noun_list.append(token.surface)

def depict_word_cloud(noun_list):
    ## 名詞リストの要素を空白区切りにする(word_cloudの仕様)
    noun_space = ' '.join(map(str, noun_list))
    mask_array = np.array(Image.open('sample.png'))
  
    ## word cloudの設定(フォントの設定)
    wc = WordCloud(mask=mask_array, 
                   background_color="white",
                   # カラーマップ
                   colormap="cool",
                   font_path='/System/Library/Fonts/ヒラギノ明朝 ProN.ttc', 
                   width=10000,height=10000)
    
    wc.generate(noun_space)
    ## 出力画像の大きさの指定
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    
    ## 目盛りの削除
    plt.tick_params(labelbottom=False,
                    labelleft=False,
                    labelright=False,
                    labeltop=False,
                   length=0)
    ## word cloudの表示
    plt.imshow(wc)

    plt.savefig('sample2.png')
    plt.show()

## 形態素解析の準備
t = Tokenizer()

noun_list = []
for sentence in list(df['sentences']):
    get_nouns(sentence, noun_list)

depict_word_cloud(noun_list)
```

Comment: 他の人が再現できるような実際に試したコードも質問に含めておくと回答が得られやすいと思います。可能なら png 形式での出力も試してみるといいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
コード載せました。
pngでもダメでした。

Comment: WordCloud の `to_file` メソッドを使って画像をファイルに保存してみてはどうでしょうか。`wc.to_file('sample2.png')` この場合、`width` と `height` は `500` 程度でも十分な様です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は単純化したものです。画像サイズは 1920x1080
Ubuntuのコードなのでフォントのパスは異なるけど, それ以外はたぶん動くはず
これで試すとどうでしょう

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

def plot_wordcloud(wordcloud):
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    #wordcloud.to_file("wordcloud.png")

text = 'I have a pen. I have an apple. 青い空 白い雲 海が好き'
wcloud = WordCloud(
    stopwords={'have', 'a', 'an'},
    background_color='white',
    font_path='/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc',
    width=1920, height=1080).generate(text)
plot_wordcloud(wcloud)
```

あるいは

```py
# plot_wordcloud(wcloud)
# 

# wcloud.to_file("wordcloud.png")
wcloud.to_image()
```

---

これで画像を生成した場合

- 画質が粗いものが生成される場合 … 原因不明。フォントファイルの違い？
- 画質が正常な場合 … `WordCloud`に指定してるパラメーター `width=`, `height=`, あるいは `mask=` の画像がぼやけてるなどの理由が(とりあえず)考えられます

Comment: ありがとうございます！
どうやら`mask=` の画像が低画質なのが原因のようです。